# Trying to build the Eratosthenes sieve program for prime numbers up to 100

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
    int i, j, n, num[100], sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        num[i] = i + 1;

    for (j = 2; j<=num[99]; j++)
    {
        for (n = j; n<=num[99]; n++)
        {
            num[j * n - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (num[i]!=0)
            sum = sum + num[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

This program just doesnt run correctly. The value of j never goes beyond 2.
Pleaae help me find the mistake? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what your inner loop is doing to `num`.

Comment: `num[j * n - 1]` is writing outside the array. For example, when `j == 2` and `n == 51`, `j * n - 1` is `101`.

Comment: In addition to writing outside the array, at some point `num[99]` will get set to 0, so the outer loop will terminate early.

Comment: Thanks a ton Barmer and Ian Abbott. Using j*j<=100 and n*j<=100 did the trick

Comment: Consider making your own answer, it will give you better formatting and more space than a comment.

Comment: How is it sensible to use `num[99]` for a bound at all?  It would be far more natural to just write (for example) `j < 100`.  Of course, the bounds on the `n` loop are a whole different issue. `n <= num[99]` is a *much* worse choice, leading to lots of bounds overruns.

Comment: You zap `num[99]` early on, so the `j` loop stops.  You should probably write `j < 100` (or maybe `99` — I've not checked your off-by-one operations fully).  But you should not be using `num[99]` in that `for` loop.